# Unexpected value declared by module in Angular 6

Tags: angular

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hwPrasGtHcLpegxxNBL?p=preview) I have an Angular 6 module with a related service that wraps `HttpClient`. The module is imported by the application module, and the main application component calls the service.

Problem is that I'm getting the following error:

> Unexpected value 'MyHttpService' declared by the module
>   'CoreServiceModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component
>   annotation

I checked all the imports and declarations and couldn't find the problem. Where's the error?

The module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyHttpService } from './http.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyHttpService
  ],
  exports: [
    MyHttpService
  ]
})
export class CoreServiceModule {}
```

And the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyHttpService {

  constructor(public httpx: HttpClient) {
        console.log("In the HttpClient constructor - " + this.httpx) 
  }

  call () {
        let data = { x: 1 };
        this.httpx.post('response.json', data).subscribe(result => {
            console.log("Http result = " + result);
          }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally as the error says, **`services,pipes`** should be under providers of your module, **`remove`** from **`declarations`** and add it to **`providers`**,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
  declarations : [],
  providers:[ 
     MyHttpService
  ],
  exports: [

  ]
})
```

Comment: I made the changes but still getting errors, can you take a look at the plunker?

Comment: remove HttpService from exports http://plnkr.co/edit/ATE6Jzgp3R2FT6H1DabC?p=preview

Comment: It works, but why remove it from exports? Isn't the module exporting the service?

Comment: providers will be shared when you share the module, only components needs to be exported

Answer (score 1):

Declarations are only for declarable classes

Add `MyHttpService` to `Providers`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
  providers:[ 
     MyHttpService
  ]
})
```

Comment: I made the changes but still getting errors, can you take a look at the plunker?